# Calculate / add to hex values with only certain characters

Tags: vb.net, hex

Hi i am working on a program communicating with a SPS via SerialPort.

There's some values i need to calculate and send to the SPS.

This SPS does it the following: It only uses A-F, 8, 9.  So A,B,C....F,8,9, then starts with "A" again.

That means if the SPS does F + 2 it will be 9.

F + 3 would be A.

Obviously F + 2 in vb.net gives me "11".

I am just doing "[Value] + &Hxx".

What would be a simple way to get it calculating as the SPS does? (A-F, 8, 9 only)

TiA

Comment: Might help to give details of the SPS, maybe there is some standard for this numbering system.  Barring that could just use an dictionary with the "Hex" value and integer value to find the say "F" and know it represents a 7

Comment: So are you saying that you are receiving a `byte` value that contains a value from 8 to 15? And you want to treat them as a cyclical sequence in the order 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 8, 9?

Comment: @John yes, almost. I am not acutally receiving the values, my program needs to calculate them the same way the SPS does. So if the SPS calculates "A + 8" it will be A again as it starts over after A-F, 8,9. And i need to calculate it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```vb
Private values As Byte() = {&HA, &HB, &HC, &HD, &HE, &HF, &H8, &H9}

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(Add(&HA, 3).ToString("X"))
    Console.WriteLine(Add(&HF, 5).ToString("X"))
    Console.WriteLine(Add(&H9, 25).ToString("X"))
End Sub

Private Function Add(startingValue As Byte, steps As Integer) As Byte
    Dim startingIndex = Array.IndexOf(values, startingValue)
    Dim finalIndex = (startingIndex + steps) Mod values.Length
    Dim finalValue = values(finalIndex)

    Return finalValue
End Function
```